# How to get serial number of a device using IOKit in iOS8 as IOPlatformSerialNumber giving nil value

Tags: ios, ios8, jailbreak, ipod, iokit

I was wondered to know how to get serial number of a device using `IOKit` in iOS8? I used `UIDevice+serialNumber` and I am able to get serial number in iOS6 and7. In iOS8 value of `platformSerialNumber` is coming `nil` in the following line:

```
CFTypeRef platformSerialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpertDevice,CFSTR("IOPlatformSerialNumber"), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
```

I am using : https://gist.github.com/0xced/566994

Note:My app will not go to app store, its for inhouse. So I am looking for something more concrete that will never change, either String or integer

Comment: I added the jailbreak tag since this is a not for app store question, not sure that that's the right tag, he could be distributing via an Enterprise account.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in iOS 8, hardware information, such as the serial number, is protected. If you want to retrieve this value, you must sign your app with private entitlements. I'm not sure if it's possible to use private entitlements in enterprise apps, and they certainly can't be used for App Store apps, but this question is tagged with jailbreak so I'll provide a solution for that.

If you want the serial number to track devices your company owns, I'd recommend taking advantage of a service like Apple's mobile device management (MDM). This gives you access to a large amount of information about devices, and allows you to manage them remotely.

If you're simply looking for an identifier that will never change for other purposes, I'd recommend using the device's UDID instead. I was able to get this on my device without entitlements, however that may be due to my phone being jailbroken. I've been told by others that entitlements are, in fact, required. More information about this can be found on the [iPhoneDevWiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Updating_extensions_for_iOS_7#Accessing_the_device.27s_UDID).

Code:

```
- (NSString *)udid
{
    void *gestalt = dlopen("/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    CFStringRef (*MGCopyAnswer)(CFStringRef) = (CFStringRef (*)(CFStringRef))(dlsym(gestalt, "MGCopyAnswer"));
    return CFBridgingRelease(MGCopyAnswer(CFSTR("UniqueDeviceID")));
}
```

Entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.private.MobileGestalt.AllowedProtectedKeys</key>
<array>
    <string>UniqueDeviceID</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Returned null in iOS version 7.1.1

Comment: I'm interested in this, can you tell me more how to do with entitlements? What have I add to this file in order to get serial number?

Comment: @tyt_g207 You must be developing a jailbroken app to use private entitlements. I've updated my answer in case you are, but if not, I'm afraid you may be out of luck. I couldn't find any way to retrieve hardware information on iOS 8 without entitlements.

Comment: Indeed, I have tested libMobileGestalt but some of keys are not retrievable.   I do not develop apps for jailbroken devices. Apple add the more and more restrictions :(

Answer (score 2):

**Reminder: This is only applicable to non-App Store apps (such as those intended for in-house distribution, or for jailbroken devices). If you submit this code to Apple it WILL get rejected.**

The following is an IOKit-based approach that retrieves the battery's serial number, which is a good static, unique ID for the device that will be the same across all apps on a given device. The following code works for iOS 8 and 9, but will not work for older versions.

```
- (NSString *) deviceUniqueID
{
    mach_port_t iokitPort = 0;
    CFMutableDictionaryRef properties;
    IOMasterPort(0, &iokitPort);
    CFDictionaryRef serviceName = IOServiceNameMatching("charger");

    io_service_t service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(iokitPort, serviceName);

    if (service == 0)
        return nil;

    kern_return_t status = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(service,
                                                             &properties,
                                                             kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                             kNilOptions);

    IOObjectRelease(service);

    if (status == KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary *)(properties);
        NSData *batteryIDData = dict[@"battery-id"];

        CFRelease(properties);

        if ([batteryIDData isKindOfClass: [NSData class]])
            return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[batteryIDData bytes]];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This code requires a bunch of IOKit symbols. You could include the necessary IOKit headers, but that can be a bit of a pain. Assuming you're not using IOKit elsewhere, just add the following declarations and it should compile fine:

```
typedef mach_port_t io_object_t;
typedef io_object_t io_registry_entry_t;
typedef io_object_t io_iterator_t;
typedef io_object_t io_connect_t;
typedef io_object_t io_service_t;

typedef UInt32 IOOptionBits;


kern_return_t IOMasterPort(mach_port_t bootstrapPort,  mach_port_t *masterPort);

CFMutableDictionaryRef IOServiceNameMatching( const char *name );

io_service_t IOServiceGetMatchingService ( mach_port_t masterPort, CFDictionaryRef matching );

kern_return_t IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(io_registry_entry_t entry,
                                                CFMutableDictionaryRef *properties,
                                                CFAllocatorRef allocator,
                                                IOOptionBits options);

kern_return_t IOObjectRelease (io_object_t object);
```

Now, as for getting it to link, you will need to add the IOKit.framework into your app. On most systems it should be available at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get the serial number under iOS8. I'm pretty sure it is no longer permitted. Apple now wants you to use the ASIdentifierManager's

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSUUID *advertisingIdentifier
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/index.html for more detail.

Note: You will get rejected if you use this and either don't serve ads or change the apps behavior in response to a previously served ad. We do the later, got rejected still, but then explained in our submission notes exactly what we use it for (and we were accepted.)

Comment: Will it change once app is deleted and installed again?

Comment: No, but it will change when the user goes to Setting > Privacy etc... and resets the advertising index. Sorry, that's the way Apple wants it.

Comment: I agree with you Paul, But my app will not go to app store, its for inhouse. So I am looking for something more concrete that will never change.

Comment: ahhh, ok, please edit your question to say that. It changes everything.

Comment: For in-house apps there are plenty of IOKit properties that are unique to a device that will never change. Examples include camera serial numbers (both front and back cameras), and battery serial numbers, all of which are currently (as of iOS 9) available on non-jailbroken devices. Obviously if you're submitting to App Store those are prohibited, but for in-house they should do fine.

Comment: @ldoogy - That's pretty cool. You should change your comment to an answer. Get some free internet points! :- )

Comment: @PaulCezanne just did that. Each point is worth $1,000 right? :-)