# Permenant unique device identifier

Tags: ios

Is there a way to identify a device even after having uninstalled an app and reinstalling again? I found [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925481/how-to-get-a-unique-device-id-in-swift) where it's possible to get a UUID but it seems that after uninstalling the app the value of the UUID changes

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

I installed an App called [Jodel](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/jodel/id789870026?l=en), you don't have to create an Account to use the app and After uninstalling it, delete iCloud data, logging out from iCloud... an reinstalling it I was still logged in in the App. I assume they use a unique device identifier? Do you have an idea how such mechanism could be implemented?

Comment: Also take a look at my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760472/private-unique-device-identifier-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Keychain Service** to store data still after uninstalling app from device.

for more reference about keychain service check this

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's Possible

```
#import "UICKeyChainStore.h"
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    [self getDeviceIdFromKeychain];
}

- (void)getDeviceIdFromKeychain 
{
    NSString *deviceID = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"KEY TO SAVE TO Keychain" service:nil];

    // if vandorid from keychain is not nil
    if (deviceID)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceID forKey:@"deviceID"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    // else it goes for new vendorid and then stored it to keychan
    else if (deviceID == (id)[NSNull null] || deviceID.length == 0 )
    {
        deviceID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

        [UICKeyChainStore setString:deviceID forKey:@"KEY TO SAVE TO Keychain"  service:nil];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceID forKey:@"deviceID"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // NSLog(@"VendorID Local - %@",deviceID);
    }
}
```

ViewContoller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSString *strDeviceId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"deviceID"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would the user be able to bypass this by deleting manually the keychain data?

Comment: @j.doe  No user cannot delete manually keychain data.

Comment: Actually you can delete keychain data by erasing your device and setting it up as new ;-) You still have the same device in your hands but to all 3rd party apps and services it is now an entirely new device.